# Solving the PDE $(x+z)u_{x} + y u_{y} + (z+y^{2})u_{z} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

sorry im new to PDEs. i  attempted to solve the following PDE.
$$(x+z)u_{x} + y u_{y} + (z+y^{2})u_{z} = 0$$

what I had done was the following

i first let $$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dz}{z+y^{2}}$$

then i got it in this form:
$$\frac{dz}{dy} - \frac{1}{y}z = y$$

this a linear ODE so I solved it and got
$$z = y^{2}$$

so i let $$\Psi_{1} = z - y^{2}$$

but when I substitute this into the original PDE I don't get it to equal zero. so I'm assuming it is not a solution. could someone please assist

Comment: The solution is actually $z=cy+y^2$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: oh i see i forgot to add the homogeneous thank you

Comment: The command of Maple `pdsolve((x + z)*diff(u(x, y, z), x) + y*diff(u(x, y, z), y) + (y^2 + z)*diff(u(x, y, z), z) = 0)` produces $$u(x,y,z)=\textit{_}\mathit{F1}\left(\frac{-y^{2}+z}{y},-\frac{\ln(y) (-y^{2}+z)+y^{2}-x}{y}\right) .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+z)u_{x} + y u_{y} + (z+y^{2})u_{z} = 0$$
Charpit-Lagrange EDOs :
$$\frac{dx}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z+y^2}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z+y^2}$
$$\frac{z}{y}-y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}$ with $z=c_1y+y^2$ :

$\frac{dx}{x+c_1y+y^2}=\frac{dy}{y}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{y}=y+c_1\quad$ which is a first order linear ODE. The solution is :

$\frac{x}{y}-y-c_1y\ln(y)=c_2$

$\frac{x}{y}-y-(\frac{z}{y}-y)y\ln(y)=c_2$

$$\frac{x}{y}-y+(y^2-z)\ln(y)=c_2$$

A third charectedristic equation comes from $du=0$
$$u=c_3$$

The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$ is :
$$\Phi\left(\frac{z}{y}-y\:\:,\:\:\frac{x}{y}-y+(y^2-z)\ln(y)\: \:,\:\: u  \right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of three vatiables.

Or equivalently :
$$u=F\left(\frac{z}{y}-y\:\:,\:\:\frac{x}{y}-y+(y^2-z)\ln(y)\right)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.